# Two select statements on same table and get Count(*)

Tags: mysql

Im trying to do two queries on the same table to get the Count(*) value.

I have this

```
SELECT `a`.`name`, `a`.`points` FROM `rank` AS a WHERE `id` = 1
```

And in the same query I want to do this

```
SELECT `b`.`Count(*)` FROM `rank` as b WHERE `b`.`points` >= `a`.`points`
```

I tried searching but did not find how to do a `Count(*)` in the same query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you would not intermingle a non aggregate and aggregate query together in MySQL.  You might do this in databases which support analytic functions, such as SQL Server, but not in (the current version of) MySQL.  That being said, your second query can be handled using a correlated subquery in the select clause the first query.  So you may try the following:

```
SELECT
    a.name,
    a.points,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rank b WHERE b.points >= a.points) AS cnt
FROM rank a
WHERE a.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from the question, you want to find out in a table for a given id how many rows have the points greater than this row. This can be achieved using full join.

```
select count(*) from rank a join rank b on(a.id != b.id) where a.id=1 and b.points >= a.points;
```